# Binding Jquery Event to All Elements Starting With Specified Characters

Tags: jquery, html

Hi is there is any way i can specify starting characters of any element to bind event with. e.g i want to bind the following event

```
$('.some-class').bind({ .... });
```

with elements starting id= {cmt_01, cmt_02, cmt_03...} dynamically generated elements.

```
e.g <div id="cmt_01"></div>
<div id="cmt_02"></div>
<div id="cmt_03"></div>
.......
```

I want to bind event with all div elements starting with character "cmt"

Can any one give me good example for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using the following:

```
​var els = $('​​​​​[id^=cmt]').bind(/*...*/);
alert (els.length); // for instance
```

...but there may be better ways to solve this problem (e.g., adding a `cmt` class and using `$('.cmt')` than using IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, both with id and class worked. i follow your suggestion and used class instead of ids..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the ["Attribute Starts With" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^="cmt"]').bind({ ... });
```

I suspect the performance will be better if you specify that the elements are `div`s:

```
$('div[id^="cmt"]').bind({ ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think using class as suggested above will be better than using id for jquery selector.